# 2D Arrays in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a 2D array.

```
string[,] my2DArr= new string[r,c];

string actual="header1,header2,header3";
```

I want to achieve copying a row to zeroth row of 2d array:

```
my2DArr[0]=actual.Split(',');

GridView gv= new GridView();
gv.AutoGeneratedColumns=true;
gv.DataSource=my2DArr;
gv.DataBind();
```

This is not showing the data. 
any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't work with lists?

```
List<List<string>> my2DArray = new List<List<string>>();
my2DArray.Add(actual.Split(',').ToList());
```

Update: When you want to bind it, you might need to use this code:

```
List<string[]> my2DArray = new List<string[]>();
my2DArray.Add(actual.Split(','));
```

Comment: that helped. I now have the 2d list how to bind this to a grideview in asp.net? i used gv.DataSource=my2DArray; gv.DataBind(); There is no error but the UI shows Capacity and count columns. I have set Auto generated columns=true/false both is the same. can you tell me why?

Comment: Please try the second version.

Comment: i used second version but its the same thing it now gives me more columns isreadonly, isfixedsize.... any changes i have todo

Comment: i have updated the editing. I want headers and the column values are present in the actual so when i split to array and assign it to Data source it should populate the data

Comment: i got it. It was taking the properties of string array. I did that in some other way. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To assign 2d array to gridview , here is code .
To  add a new row , you can add 
new ListItem("Header1", "Header2");

```
 ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
 arrList.Add(new ListItem("Header1", "Header2") );

               for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
               {

                   arrList.Add(new ListItem(array[i, 0], array[i, 1]));

               }

               GridView1.DataSource = arrList;

               GridView1.DataBind();
```